# Eclipse Helios manage Weblogic 9.2

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I have installed Eclipse Helios on my linux workstation and would like to manage a Weblogic 9.2 application server install.  I search the server runtime enviroments and there is no option for Weblogic only Oracle.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987061/how-to-work-with-weblogic-in-eclipse/2013108#2013108 explains how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out on the OTN that they have a Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.  The Helios version is not yet released.  Will have to wait for that.
Thanks,
Tom
[link text](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4444043#4444043)

Answer (score 1):

Update site for Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/helios

Answer (score 0):

Oracle purchased BEA a while back; I don't have Helios, yet, however, maybe you can find the option under the Oracle options?

Comment: Under the Oracle options it just has OC4J 10.1.3 and OC4J 10.1.3n