# How to use eclipse with weblogic server

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I have been trying to solve this problem using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987061/how-to-work-with-weblogic-in-eclipse) but it couldn't solve my problem.

What i did is this--

I installed weblogic server inside a folder on my desktop.
Now i want to use this weblogic server with eclipse.
Do i need to download additional adapters or do i need to do something else to configure weblogic with eclipse since i have already installed weblogic on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be a case of creating a new server in Eclipse and specifying the installation location.

Before beginning, you should make sure that you have the "Java EE" flavour of Eclipse installed.

1. Open up Eclipse.
2. Go to the Servers view.
3. Right-click in the Servers view and select New > Server.
4. In the filter box type 'weblogic'. This should show one option (I forget the exact name of it. Something like weblogic adapter tools.
5. Select this and complete the wizard. You'll be prompted to restart Eclipse once it completes.
6. After Eclipse has restarted, repeat steps 2,3, and 4. Except this time, the  you should get a selection of servers that you can create. You should be able to create BEA/Oracle weblogic servers at multiple versions.
7. Select the one for the version that you have downloaded and click Next.
8. Provide paths to WebLogic home and Java home and complete the wizard.

[image]

Comment: ,when i click at "download additional adapters" ,it shows multiple options but none of them is similar to what is shown in your screenshot.What shall i do now?

Comment: @a874 Sorry, I should have made it clear. That screenshot is AFTER I've gone through steps 1-5. In the first instance you need to download the adapter tools (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Does it mean that i should choose any of the options shown ?

Comment: I've just had a look through what I actually installed and it has the following description --- 

"Oracle WebLogic Server Tools
Part of Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.2.1.2.1

Tools for developing applications for Oracle WebLogic Server (versions 12.2.x, 12.1.x, 10.3.x, 10.0 and 9.2)."

Comment: Out of all the options shown,none of them is for weblogic server in my eclipse.

Comment: I have set the path for JAVA_HOME but what's the meaning of path for weblogic ?

Comment: That'll be where you installed it. You said in your question -- "I installed weblogic server inside a folder on my desktop." -- It's this location you need to specify.

Comment: But it's giving this error--"The path "C:\Users\Asad\Desktop\weblogic" does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install"

Comment: I have installed weblogic in this folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108045/discussion-between-adam-rice-and-a874).

Comment: when selecting an installed weblogic server runtime, you have to choose the "wlserver" folder inside your installation folder. Otherwise eclipse will not detect the server. In your example, this would be "C:\Users\Asad\Desktop\weblogic\wlserver" or something similar

Comment: I got this error  when I did this steps :  Software being installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 17.2.0.201806071916 (oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.feature.group 17.2.0.201806071916)Software currently installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.13.1.v20171009-0410 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.13.1.v20171009-0410)Only one of the following can be installed at once: Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency:Cannot satisfy dependency: